# Is there a way to change default link in php?

Tags: php, hyperlink

The default link I get is to link **index.php**.
How can I change the default link to all my project to **index.php?folder=0**?

Comment: You should look at .htaccess redirect

Comment: is there a way to code using php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `GET` starting in `index.php` file.
If `$_GET['folder']` is not set then redirect otherwise load same page.

```
if(!isset($_GET['folder'])){
    header("Location:./index.php?folder=0");
}
```

Hope this work to you.

Comment: it continuously loads the index.php

Comment: Can you show me how you set condition?, For me, it works.

Comment: `<?php 
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_GET['folder'])){
    header("Location:./index.php?folder=0");
  }
?>`

Comment: Try to remove ./ in url ```header("Location:index.php?folder=0"); } ?> ```

Comment: So print ```$_GET``` before put this condition and confirm you get correct value in ```$_GET``` or not otherwise here no more rocket science work I just check variable set condition if set then load page otherwise reload page and params in URL.

Comment: Hi, sir thank you for the time answering the question. It works now I didn't put it in the index.php file instead I put it in the file where I do the $_GET function.

Comment: ^ yes, that would be the reason why it would redirect constantly ;) Glad you got it to work

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
<?php
   $sec = 0;
   $page = '?folder=0';
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you try to use the html meta refresh instead?

Comment: Hi, sir thank you for answering my question. I got now my answer.